# Problems to use value from slice in redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

i have a problem to use a value that is store in a slice.
I have this slice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = '';

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'token',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setToken: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload);
      return action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { setToken } = userSlice.actions;
const { reducer } = userSlice;
export default reducer;
```

Just to store the token.

i have a component that use a function to get the token, and i use dispatch in this component to store the token.

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useState } from "react";
import ChatDesign from "../../designResponses/ChatDesign";
import LateralWindow from "../../designResponses/LateralWindow";
import { setToken } from "../../../slices/userSlice.js";
import { getAccessTokenApi } from '../../../api/auth.js';

const ResponseDesign = ( ) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const token = getAccessTokenApi(); //get the token  
  dispatch(setToken(token)); // send the token to my slice to store

  const sendtoken = useSelector(state=>state.userToken);
  console.log(sendtoken);  //when i do this, i see the token like a string.

  const [placeToShow, setPlaceToShow ] = useState('chat');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setPlaceToShow(event.target.value);
  };
  console.log(placeToShow);

  return (       
    <div className="container-fluidr m-3" >
      <form className="needs-validation" >
        // here is the form
      </form>
      <div>
        {placeToShow === 'chat' ? <ChatDesign placeToShow={placeToShow} token={sendtoken}/> :  <> <ChatDesign placeToShow={placeToShow} token={sendtoken}/>  <LateralWindow /> </> }     
      </div>                 
    </div>
```

then i pass the token like a prop to the next component.

In the next component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setDesignResponse } from '../../slices/responseDesignSlice.js';
import { createNewVariations } from '../../slices/variationsSlice.js';
import { createNewJsonResponse } from '../../slices/new_responseDesignSlice.js';

const ChatDesign = ({placeToShow, token}) => {
  //in this console still i see the token like a string
  console.log(token);
  const generalInfo = useSelector(state=> state.faqsGralInfo); 
  const {
    description,
    typeResponse,
    rolViews,
    workLoadLevel,
    id,
    id_intent,
    corpusArea,
    corpusName
  } = generalInfo;

  const variations = useSelector(state=> state.variationsList);
  console.log(variations);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [ dataResponse, setDataResponse ] = useState({ 
    placeToShow: placeToShow,
    title: '',
    text: '',
    link: '',
    linkTitle: '',
    image: '',
    imageTitle: '',     
  });  
  
  const [ newJsonResponse, setNewJsonResponse ] = useState({
    response_json_new: {},
    description, 
    typeResponse,
    rolViews, 
    workLoadLevel, 
    id, 
    id_intent,     
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setDataResponse({...dataResponse, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    setNewJsonResponse({...newJsonResponse,
      description, 
      typeResponse,
      rolViews, 
      workLoadLevel, 
      id, 
      id_intent, 
      response_json_new:dataResponse, 
      corpusArea, 
      corpusName,
    });
    
  };  
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault();   
    dispatch(setDesignResponse(dataResponse));    
    dispatch(createNewVariations(variations));
    // here i pass the token like a param
    dispatch(createNewJsonResponse(newJsonResponse, token)); 
    
  };

  return (
    <>
      
      <div className="card mb-3">
        <div className="card-body">
          <form className="row" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            // other form  
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </>
  );
};

export default ChatDesign;
```

At the en in the final slice where i want to use the token like a string:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import FaqsService from '../services/faqs.service';

const initialState = {
  response_json_new: { },    
};

export const createNewJsonResponse = createAsyncThunk (
  "new-json-response/post",
  async (responseData, token) => { 
    console.log( 'user:  ', token );  

    const res = await FaqsService.createNewResponse( responseData);
    return res.data;
  }
);

const NewdesignResponse = createSlice ({
  name: 'new_designResponse',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setNewDesignResponse: (state, action) => {  
      return {
        response_json_new: action.payload
      };
    }
  },
});    
export const { setNewDesignResponse } = NewdesignResponse.actions;
```

The console.log of the token show in console this:

[image]

I don't understant why in the component the token is string, but when i use inside the other place has this aspect.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to return anything from setToken instead assign  `action.payload` to the state object in the setToken function of the reducer

```
setToken: (state, action) => {
   state = action.payload
}
```

and in ResponseDesign conponent get token from redux store

```
const sendtoken = useSelector(state=>state.token);
```